# Shopify api created_at_min date format

Tags: c#, shopify, orders

I want to retrieve orders only after certain date. Based on [DOCUMENTATION](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order)

created_at_min is in this format: 
**2014-04-25T16:15:47-04:00**

My database time is as such:
**2019-11-20 12:19:57.650**

What is their format of time? How can I format to their format type ? My database time is c# Datetime.Now

Comment: Is you database returning a string or a DateTime object.  The Request is a string so I need to know if you have to convert a DateTime object to a string; or convert a string (date) to another string (date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Convert.ToDateTime(s);` to convert from string to datetime and also you can convert string to datetiem using `ToString`

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss");
```

For more information you can check this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) and [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1)